# Can " multiplicative inverse of $\frac nm = \frac mn$" be obtained directly from the definition of multiplicative inverse: " inverse of $n=\frac 1n$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, binary-operations

Note : from, if I dare say, a semantic point of view, " multiplicative inverse of a number $N$ " is clearly defined as " a number $M$ such that $N\times M = M\times N = 1$" ( the multiplicative identity). My question deals with the syntactic aspect of the inverse, I mean , with the syntactic manipulations and transformations in which a multiplicative inverse can be involved.

---

- At first sight, it looks as though there were two definitions of " multiplicative inverse" :

(1) multplicative inverse of a single number $n$ , that is, $\frac 1n$

(2) multiplicative inverse of a quotient of two numbers $\frac nm$ , that is $\frac mn$.

- Which definition should be considered as prior?
- Should one consider that the most fundamental one is the second, and that, in the first definition,   number $n$ has to be understood implicitly as $\frac n1$ : in that case , multiplicative inverse means in general : " the reverse fraction $\frac mn$ ", and $\frac 1n$ has to be considered as a particular case.
- Or is it the other way round? In that case , the primitive definition of inverse is $\frac 1n$ and $\frac mn$ is a particular case.
- If I am correct, it is the second answer that is the standard one.
- But it brings the question : ***how to derive : " inverse of $\frac nm = \frac mn$" from  " inverse of $n = \frac 1n$"***?

Comment: $(\frac{a}{b})^{-1}=(a\times \frac{1}{b})^{-1}=(a)^{-1}(\frac{1}{b})^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}\times b = \frac{b}{a}$

Comment: Alternatively, $\frac{n}{m}\times \frac{m}{n}=\frac{nm}{nm} = 1$

Comment: @JMoravitz. - Do you think I can easily do the same thing with fractions , I mean, going from $\frac {1} {\frac nm}$ to  $ \frac mn$  through a series of transformations ( without using exponents.

Comment: @RayLittleRock I think you can prove that from the group axioms. All we're doing is getting rid of division because it's not associative and associativity is incredibly powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize that $$\frac{m}{n}=m\cdot\frac1n$$ and the property that the multiplicative inverse of a product is the product of the multiplicative inverses of each factor.

The multiplicative inverse of $m$ is $\dfrac1m$ and the multiplicative inverse of $\dfrac1n$ is $n$.  Therefore, the multiplicative inverse of $\dfrac{m}{n}$ is $$\frac1m\cdot n=\frac{n}{m}$$ as desired.